Should infinitive or ing-form be used after "help"?
I was proofreading a user guide for a website and found this sentence:

If you see that they are missing, you can help adding them.

It didn't sound wrong to me, but grammar checking tools suggested changing it. LanguageTool suggested replacing "help adding" with "help to add", which to me sounds not totally wrong, but a bit more awkward than "help adding". (LanguageTool pointed to this VOA article for an explanation; it discusses ing-forms and infinitives, but doesn't address the verb "help" specifically).
Grammarly suggested changing it to "help add", which sounds outright wrong. However, I am really not an English expert, even though I write English quite a lot, so I might be mistaken. So what is the best way to write this? And is there an explanation for this?

"Help by adding" might be what is needed, but more context is needed to be sure.

I would expect either help to add (assist others in the task) or help by adding (add 'them', which will be helpful).

Not sure why this was closed... it is about as on-topic as can be for ELU.

This is a duplicate of A gerund after 'to help'? However, the answer here is far better. But should it not be posted at the original?

@EdwinAshworth No, it isn't. For a start, no question is a dupe of an unanswered question. Secondly, there is the control aspect of the subject of the participle. Thirdly, there is the negative polarity item cant help doing. There's much more besides.

@Araucaria - Him You're using the stipulative definition; I'm using the English language definition. The essential question is the same (though this adds a second question about other licensed catenations). And you'll find that 'can't help doing' is addressed there also. I can only guess about why you're finding fault about my observation and recommendation. I have said that the answer here needs keeping. If not here.

@EdwinAshworth Throw-away comments under questions are ephemeral and may be deleted at any time. John Lawler's comment there cannot be construed as 'addressing' the 'can't help doing'. The reason for my comment is that I have become vigilant about over-hasty duping.

How about joining me in CVing the earlier duplicate, then. Searchability and lack of bloat are a hallmark of the site. //Not all comments are throw-away. Sometimes, some users think that valuable contributions not really deserving of 'answer' status  (perhaps because of lack of a supporting reference) are validly put in 'comments'.

Help allows both a plain infinitival complement and a to-infinitival complement when it's a verb. The -ing clause as complement is marginally acceptable at best.
In the Corpus of Contemporary American English the results for 'he helped...' are as follows:

plain infinitival 329
to-infinitival 232
-ing clause 2

Only one of the -ing clause examples could actually be argued as a complement to help.

Snape's logic and deductive reasoning skills were such that he helped
protecting the Philosopher's Stone by creating an obstacle (Harry
Potter Wiki)

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language has verb help on p1229 as  allowing to-infinitivals and bare infinitivals, but not gerund-participials (-ing clauses).
Then again, ngrams gives 'help adding' as quite a common colocation, more so even than 'help add' or 'help to add':

However, most of these hits are noun uses.
In fact, when a noun, help can be followed by -ing clauses. The string 'some help doing something' returns 251 hits in the Corpus of Contemporary American English. These are quite acceptable:

Want some help finding that dog?
I knew you'd need some help keeping it real.
Maybe he'd like some help cleaning it out.

Then there's also can help in non-affirmative contexts which only licenses -ing clause complements (CGEL p1232) as in No one can help liking her. These make up the vast majority of hits for 'can help doing something' in the Corpus of Contemporary American English.
In the sentence given though, help is quite definitely a verb, and used in an affirmative context, so it would be best to have either a plain infinitival or to-infinitival following it.

Another possibility, as others have mentioned, is the solution of adding a by before the -ing clause to make it an adjunct of means, which in this case may be preferable if the person helping is in fact adding all of them; however, helping add them, or helping to add them by adding some but not all, is also perfectly possible.

"I can't help ...-ing" sounds idiomatic to me, but I guess the phrase "can't help" is just a special case...

@Heinzi Yep, also included as a separate listing in The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language as gerund-participial only on p1232.

... Yes; 'I Just Can't Help Believin/g // Feeling // Falling // ...' are common, especially in lyrics. But as Heinzi points out, 'help' doesn't mean 'aid [in]' here, but 'prevent [myself]'.

Of the first ten hits for "help adding" in the 1962-2019 interval, one is of the 'can't help' type, and the other nine are false positives (often with 'help' nounal, or a section heading in a manual). //// 'I would like to help finding where the issue is' is borderline acceptable imo; it acknowledges that this might involve quite a lengthy process. / Perhaps there's a deleted 'in'.

It's definitely complex, with a lot of similar but distinct forms. I find a few results online like "if you can help cleaning", "can I help clearing up", etc, which have the meaning help=assist and seem a bit odd, but might be influenced by "can't help doing". It's also quite common to find things like "can I help you doing...?" which is a different construction again.

@Stuart F Usages that are only/more idiomatic in negative environments (negations and interrogatives) are negative polarity items.
